# Nesting a slot in a slot for vue

Tags: vue.js, nested, slot

**Update: Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve here (from the threaded conversation below):**

> Accept Component A - Accept Component B - Accept a condition - if
>   condition is true : wrap Component B with Component A [and render]- else only
>   render component B.

**I'm** interested in **creating a component that renders a wrapper conditionally**. I figured **a theoretical approach** like this would probably be best**:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <slot v-if="wrapIf" name="wrapper">
            <slot name="content"></slot>
        </slot>

        <slot v-else name="content"></slot>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            wrapIf: Boolean,
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then when we **implement**, it would look **something like this:**

```
...
<wrapper-if :wrap-if="!!link">
    <a :href="link" slot="wrapper"><slot></slot></a>

    <template slot="content">
         content
    </template>
</wrapper-if>
```

The idea being that, in this case, **if there *is* a link,** then let's **wrap the content with the wrapper slot (which can be any component/element).** **If there *isn't***, then let's **just render the content** without the wrapped link. Pretty simple logic, but it seems that I'm misunderstanding some basic vue functionality because **this particular example does not work.**

**What is wrong with my code** or **is there some kind of native api** that already achieves this **or** perhaps **a dependency that does this** sort of thing already?

The output should look like this:

`wrapIf === true`

```
<a href="some.link">
    content
</a>
```

`wrapIf === false`

```
content
```

Answer (score 1):

Just focus on the content itself, and let the component worry about whether or not to wrap the [default](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Default-Slot-Content) or [named](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots) content slot.

If you need the wrapper to be dynamic, a [dynamic component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) should solve that. I've updated my solution accordingly. So if you need the wrapper to be a `label` element, just set the `tag` property to it, and so on and so forth.

```js
const WrapperIf = Vue.extend({
  template: `
    <div>
      <component :is="tag" v-if="wrapIf" class="wrapper">
        <slot name="content"></slot>
      </component>

      <slot v-else name="content"></slot>
    </div>
  `,

  props: ['wrapIf', 'tag']
});


new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      link: 'https://stackoverflow.com/company',

      tagList: ['p', 'label'],
      tag: 'p',
      wrap: true
    }
  },

  components: {
    WrapperIf
  }
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}

p.wrapper {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

label.wrapper {
  background-color: lavender;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <wrapper-if :wrap-if="wrap" :tag="tag">
    <a :href="link" slot="content">
       content
    </a>
  </wrapper-if>

  <div>
    Change wrapper type:
    <select v-model="tag">
      <option v-for="tag in tagList">{{tag}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <button @click="wrap = !wrap">Toggle wrapper</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this solution assumes a static wrapper component/element. Both the wrapper and the content will arbitrary. I apologize if I didn't make that clear. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Answer updated. Please let me know if that addresses your issue.

Comment: This still seems to wrap the link around the content despite `wrap === false`

Comment: @Philll_t The problem is that you are using the same value for both setting the content and the visibility state (by doing `!!link`), which when the `link` does content a URL, it **will** render the wrapper, since you are coercing (boolean conversion) the value from the same source. That is why for this purpose, I'm using a separate value called `wrap`, inside of the data.

Comment: Despite the conversion issue, the component should do the following:
- Accept Component A
- Accept Component B
- Accept a condition
- if condition is true : wrap Component B with Component A
- else only render component B.

Comment: @Philll_t I believe the above solution satisfies those conditions. Let me know what you think.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the solution, but it seems that the`<a/>` (component a) is wrapping `"content"` (component b) despite the condition (`wrap`) being false?

Comment: @Philll_t Can you please share your updated code showing this issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186689/discussion-between-philll-t-and-jom).